# Jquery countdown is not working (wrong time)

Tags: jquery, countdown

I am using this **[CountDown Plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)**, here is my code and view:

```
<div class="sc" lang="2013, 12 -1, 18">
<div class="sc" lang="2013, 6 -1, 22">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".sc").each(function(){
$(this).countdown({until: $(this).attr("lang"), compact: true, format: 'HMS', description: ''});});});
</script>
```

My problem is it returns wrong time, example: **00:34:00** and the other is **00:34:03**.

Could anyone help me?

*I'm trying to learn English, so i speak English not well, so sorry.*

Comment: What exactly you want. How it should be listed ?

Comment: You have given `HSM`, so it list `H:M:S`.

Comment: You are getting `00:34:03` after `00:34:00` ?

Comment: @sahal the first div, it shows `00:34:00` and the other div, it shows `00:34:03` (late 3 seconds)

Comment: @Boulevard so they should show the same despite `lang` being different?

Comment: and time left is wrong, the date end is so far from current date.

Comment: @antony i tried with `id` attribute but it returns the same problem.

Comment: @Boulevard can you explain what the numbers in `2013, 12 -1, 18` mean?

Comment: @antony day: 18, month: 12, year: 2013.

Comment: You need to use `Date` function and `space` between date is wrong, You should trim it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the until parameter incorrectly, you need a new Date object there and your current lang attr cannot be parsed into that.

**EDIT:** Since your target date is so far away it would be better if you used `ODHMS` or `DHMS` as your format to include months and days as needed.

I have made some changes to your code to make it work.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sc" lang="2013, 11, 18"></div>
<div class="sc" lang="2013, 5, 22"></div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.sc").each(function (i, item) {
        var targetDate = $(item).attr("lang").split(',');
        $(item).countdown({
            until: new Date(targetDate[0].trim(), targetDate[1].trim(), targetDate[2].trim()),
            compact: true,
            format: 'DHMS',
            description: ''
        });
    });
});
```

Also check a working sample in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EkmsT/

**EDIT 2 :** I have changed the lang values to 11 and 5 instead of 12-1 and 6-1 and used it directly in the countdown code as targetDate[1].trim(). You can still use 12 -1 and 6 -1 and change the new Date code to use parseInt(targetDate[1].trim())

Comment: parseInt(targetDate[1].trim()) if in his code he subtracted 1 from month else it will display NAN

Comment: @JobertEnamno Yes, which is why i actually did the calculation manually and changed the values to 11 and 5 within the HTML tag. I will edit my answer to explain this within.

Answer (score 1):

well its because timezone is not set.

try this.

`$(this).countdown({until: $(this).attr("lang"), compact: true, format: 'HMS', description: '',timezone: +60});`

Set timezone accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `date` function while defining the `until` argument in jquery count down. And There is a space between the date in `lang` attr.

```
<div class="sc" lang="2013, 10, 21"></div>
<div class="sc" lang="2013, 5, 23"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".sc").each(function(){
    var dateSplit = $(this).attr("lang").split(',');alert(dateSplit[0].trim());
    var dateRem = new Date(dateSplit[0].trim(), dateSplit[1].trim(), dateSplit[2].trim());
    $(this).countdown({until: dateRem, compact: true, format: 'HMS', description: ''});});
});
</script>
```